# Disable replace preview on click in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a similar question to this issue https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/41581

How do you disable the open of a replace preview on click of a find and replace item in a file in visual studio code? There doesn't seem to be a way to alter that in the user settings. I just want to be able to have find and replace text in the side menu, click on the file reported and just be taken to the file.

Answer (score 30):

A solution to this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/60027) was merged in November 2018.

Go to `File → Preferences → Settings`
and then write "replace" in the search bar and you will see the option:

[image: typing "replace" in the search bar in settings]

You can also use `"search.useReplacePreview": false` in your settings file.

Answer (score 6):

On Windows/Linux - `Ctrl + Shift + P`

On MacOS - `Cmd + Shift + P`

In the search box type `settings.json`

paste the following line there

`"search.useReplacePreview": false`

[image]